# Implementing MUI Autocomplete with Multiple Select and Filters: Need Guidance on How to Achieve Desired Result

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

Hello Stack Overflow community,

I am currently working on a project that requires implementing a search functionality allowing users to select multiple options and apply filters. I am undecided about whether to use Material-UI's Autocomplete component or another component/library for this task.

My requirements are as follows:

1. Multiple Select: Users should be able to select multiple options from the search dropdown.
2. Filters: The search options should be filterable based on specific criteria (for example, by category or type).

I have looked into Material-UI's Autocomplete, but I am open to exploring other components or libraries that might better suit my needs.

To provide a better understanding of my requirements, I have created a video demonstration: [text](https://imgur.com/a/cikElSL)

If you have experience implementing these features with any library or component and can provide guidance on choosing the right tool for the job, I would greatly appreciate your insights. Additionally, if you know of any resources comparing different components for similar use cases, please share your knowledge.

Thank you for your help in advance!